# NetSuite Suitescript 2.0 - Remove Member Item then Add member item based on a field on the kit

Tags: netsuite, suitescript2.0

I am working on a SuiteScript that I have pieced together from watching videos and reading various articles.

Purpose: Remove a member item from a Kit/Package item and add a new Member Item found in a Custom Field.

Some Details: We use Kit/Package item to promote the sale of general goods we have in stock under a single SKU. When we are low or out of stock we may have substitute items that can take its place. I added a custom field called, "Best Member Item" {custitem_burkett_bestmemberitem}. This field populates itself with the best alternative substitute item that we could use to fill customer orders.

Issue #1: Script is not happy about me entering just the field label for Value..
Issue #2: I tested by adding TEXT, and it complained "Skipped - Script Workflow Action : Set Best Member Item doesn't have matching audience
" 
Below is the Script.

```
define(["N/currentRecord"], function(r){
```

var rec = currentRecord.get();

```
       function insertLine(rec) {
           rec.insertLine({
               sublistId: "item",
               line: 1
           });

           rec.SetCurrentSublistValue({
               sublistId: "item",
               fieldId: "item",
               Value: {custitem_burkett_bestmemberitem},
           });

           rec.SetCurrentSublistValue({
               sublistId: "item",
               fieldId: "quantity",
               Value: 1
           });

           rec.commitLine({sublistId: "item"});
       };
```

})

Comment: Did you check whether your workflow script deployment has "all roles" checked? I believe that you will get this "matching audience" error unless you have roles defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you will need some more help before continuing further, based on the sample you gave.

I think you will need to understand and tell us what your execution context is - for example, on create of the item, on edit of the item, or on a transaction level basis.

Secondly, I am almost certain, for best practice or otherwise, N/currentRecord should only be used within client scripts. So that can be something you can research on. Your current sample will work as a 2.0 client script with a few changes...

but depending on your use case, i.e if your user will only update this in UI, or further, with csv, or both, you might need more than one script.

To me, unless there is major changes or use cases, using this as a wfa (workflow action script) is not the correct design forward..

Comment: Hello, I am attempting to modify a Kit/Package item when the availability of the component reaches 0, if a substitute is available then remove the component and add the substitute. I planned on using a workflow to identify and execute this change.  Outside of example scripts, I have 0 experience with scripting in NetSuite. Thank you again for your time.